# Is there any way to configure TFS or VS to use server workspaces by default?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

My organization was quite comfortable using server workspaces before we upgraded to TFS 2012, and the headaches that have been caused by local workspaces have been enormous and innumerable. I would very much like to disable local workspaces, or if that's impossible, to at least change the default to a server workspace so that it's not such a landmine for my users.

Is this possible? My search hasn't turned up much in the way of results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the default workspace type for a Team Project Collection.  In Team Explorer, open the Settings page and select Team Project Collection > Source Control.

[image: Team Explorer Settings page]

In the Source Control Settings dialog, select the Workspace Settings tab.  There you can select either server or local workspaces as the default.

[image: Source Control Settings Dialog]

Comment: Years of pain have just come to an end.